# Generate absent dates with the closest values

Tags: sql, date, window-functions, exasol

There is a table (mileage_event) which shows mileage of all cars.
Contains the following columns:
created_at - date,
car_id - car id,
car_mileage - mileage of a car

It is worth considering that not all days have data.
For example:

| car_id | created_at | car_mileage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d016e61c5326-f246894a | 2023-05-22 | 100000 |
| d016e61c5326-f246894a | 2023-05-26 | 105000 |
| d016e61c5326-f246894a | 2023-05-27 | 110000 |

As you can see, there are no rows for this car between 2023-05-22 and 2023-05-26 (i.e. 3 days are absent). It means that the car hadn't been on drive for these days.

What do I want: to generate the missing days and add the nearest mileage value to them.

(Note: it's Exasol database)
As a result:

| car_id | created_at | car_mileage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d016e61c5326-f246894a | 2023-05-22 | 100000 |
| d016e61c5326-f246894a | 2023-05-23 | 100000 |
| d016e61c5326-f246894a | 2023-05-24 | 100000 |
| d016e61c5326-f246894a | 2023-05-25 | 100000 |
| d016e61c5326-f246894a | 2023-05-26 | 105000 |
| d016e61c5326-f246894a | 2023-05-27 | 110000 |

Thanks in advance!

**UPD**:
I could be able to come up with this but it seems I'm wrong somewhere and do not see an error:

```
WITH date_series AS (select add_days(current_date - interval '2' year, level - 1) as dates
                from dual
                connect by level <= days_between(current_date,current_date - interval '2' year) + 1
                order by local.dates) --to constantly get only last 2 years    
,
combined AS (
    SELECT
        m.car_id as car_id,
        d.dates,
        COALESCE(m.car_mileage,
                 LAG(m.car_mileage, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY m.car_id ORDER BY d.dates)) AS car_mileage
    FROM date_series d
    LEFT JOIN mileage_event m ON d.dates = m.created_at
)
SELECT * FROM combined ORDER BY car_id, dates
```

And still I get this:
| car_id | created_at | car_mileage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d016e61c5326-f246894a | 2023-05-22 | 100000 |
| null | 2023-05-23 | null |
| null | 2023-05-24 | null |
| null | 2023-05-25 | null |
| d016e61c5326-f246894a | 2023-05-26 | 105000 |
| d016e61c5326-f246894a | 2023-05-27 | 110000 |

I get that it's left join so it obviously cannot find the right values (and shows null instead).

Comment: take a look at [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html)

Comment: @Andrew it's only used in Postgresql. Unfortunately, I'm dealing with Exasol and it doesn't have that sort of thing

Comment: Then I don't understand why this request is tagged `postgresql`. In standard SQL such tasks are solved with recursive queries. You'll probably just have to google "recursive CTE" and get a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, always good to see someone asking a legitimate question and people commenting "You should google it".

You can achieve this by leveraging common table expressions (CTEs), window functions, and joining with a series of dates. The general strategy is to:

Generate a series of dates spaning the range you're interested in.
For each car_id, use a LEFT JOIN to combine this date series with your existing mileage data.
Employ window functions to fill in the missing mileage data.
Here is how i would do it:

```
-- Create a CTE with a series of dates. Adjust the start and end dates as needed.
WITH date_series AS (
    SELECT CAST('2023-05-22' AS DATE) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER() - 1 AS created_at
    FROM (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30) -- Generating 30 days, adjust this number as needed
),

--  LEFT JOIN the date series with your mileage data and use LAG() to fill in gaps.
combined AS (
    SELECT 
        m.car_id,
        d.created_at,
        COALESCE(m.car_mileage, 
                 LAG(m.car_mileage, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY m.car_id ORDER BY d.created_at)) AS car_mileage
    FROM date_series d
    LEFT JOIN mileage_event m ON d.created_at = m.created_at
)

-- Get result
SELECT * FROM combined WHERE car_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY car_id, created_at
```

I hope that answer your question and works. Let me know if you need more help.

**UPDATE**

The issue is probably the LAG function in the combined CTE. When you are using the LAG function within the LEFT JOIN context, it will not have a car_id value to partition by for the rows that have a null car_mileage. This is why the LAG function doesn't return a value for these rows.

```
WITH date_series
AS (
    SELECT add_days(CURRENT_DATE - interval '2' year, LEVEL - 1) AS dates
    FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= days_between(CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE - interval '2' year) + 1
    ORDER BY dates
    )
    ,joined
AS (
    SELECT m.car_id AS car_id
        ,d.dates
        ,m.car_mileage
                                          
                     
    FROM date_series d
    LEFT JOIN mileage_event m ON d.dates = m.created_at
    )
SELECT car_id
    ,dates AS created_at
    ,COALESCE(car_mileage, LAG(car_mileage, 1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY dates
            )) AS car_mileage
FROM joined
ORDER BY car_id
    ,created_at;
```

Comment: Well, to google this was the only advice I was able to give, as I don't know Exasol syntax. It is supposed to be quite standard compliant, but I wouldn't have guessed it supports Oracle's `CONNECT BY` syntax, that you can safely cast '2023-05-22' to date, that you can add an integer to a date and that integer is considered a number of days then, and that it has a misnomed `DUAL` table like Oracle does. Considering all this, I still think that my advice to look up recursive queries is not that bad :-)

Comment: @Mr.Jones
Please, take a look at my update.

Comment: @Traveler See my updated respone :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Exasol syntax. In SQL you'll usually fill gaps in a series with a recursive query. All you'll do is take each row, look at their following row, if there is any, so you know how many days to add. Then add as many rows as you need.

The following is Oracle syntax. In Exasol you may have to add the keyword `RECURSIVE` or change the interval to something like `interval '1 days'` or the like. You can probably find this in the docs.

```
with cte (car_id, created_at, car_mileage, next_created_at) as
(
  select
    car_id, created_at, car_mileage,
    lead(created_at) over (partition by car_id order by created_at) as next_created_at
  from mytable
  union all
  select car_id, created_at + interval '1' day, car_mileage, next_created_at
  from cte
  where created_at + interval '1' day < next_created_at
)
select car_id, created_at, car_mileage
from cte
order by car_id, created_at;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/61_Ht136

Comment: If this should work for you and you want to accept this answer, then please edit my answer with all amendments you had to do to make the syntax work in Exasol. Thus this will be more helpful for future readers working with Exasol.